# Ms Excel Formulas for Date and Day

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need help.
I have written a specific date, for eg `13/03/2013` in **A1**.
Now I want its corresponding weekday in **A2** (i.e. `13/03/2013 (Wednesday)`.
In **A3** I want it to show two days ahead (i.e. `15/03/2013`).
If, however, the day in **A2** is `SUNDAY`, then I want to add three days in **A3**. It should show `16/03/2013 (monday)` in **A3**.

What functions/formulas should I use?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already tried? SuperUser is a place where we try to help those who themselves have tried to resolve something, but get stuck or run into a problem. You improve your chances of getting a response if you provide details of what you've already tried. This does two things; 1) lets us know you are willing to put in an effort and not expect someone else to just do it for you, and 2) helps us to not suggest what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

In A2

```
=text(A1,"dddd")
```

Or just use `=A1` and format with custom format `dddd`.

In A3

```
=if(weekday(a1)=1,A1+3,A1+2)
```

If you want to show the date, format with your preferred date format. If you want to show the weekday, format with custom format `dddd`.